# отображение данных в UITableViewController при загрузке из сети

Tags: xcode, json, swift

Какую реализацию лучше выбрать при такой задаче?

Создан `UITableViewController` для отображения строк в одной секции. При статическом создании массива данных и заполнении им `TableView` всё отлично работает. Но при загрузке данных в формате JSON по https `TableView` создаётся пустой.

```
import UIKit

class questTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var restarauntsNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "Thai Cafe"] // массив наименований ресторанов

    var apps = [AppModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*************/

        DataManager.getDataFromHttp { (httpData) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data: httpData)

            //1
            if let appArray = json[].array {
                print("OK - Array")
                //2
                //var apps = [AppModel]()

                //3
                for appDict in appArray {
                    //let appId: String? = appDict["id"].string
                    var typeStrForTmp: String? = appDict["id"].string
                    let appId = Int(typeStrForTmp!)
                    let appName: String? = appDict["name"].string

                    let app = AppModel(id: appId, name: appName)
                    self.apps.append(app)
                }

                //4
                print(self.apps)
                print("apps.count: \(self.apps.count)")
            }
        }
        /*************/


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        print("apps2.count: \(apps.count)")
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print("apps3.count: \(apps.count)")
        //return restarauntsNames.count
        return apps.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        //cell.textLabel?.text = restarauntsNames[indexPath.row]

        //cell.nameQuestLabel?.text = restarauntsNames[indexPath.row]

        //cell.nameQuestLabel?.text = apps[indexPath.row].name

        cell.imageQuestImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0 
        cell.imageQuestImageView.clipsToBounds = true 
        print("apps4.count: \(apps.count)")
        return cell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Получается так, что с начала выводится таблица, а потом формируются данные с сервера.

Comment: почему бы после получения данных с сервера не сделать reload?

Comment: при добавлении строки self.tableView.reloadData() после //4 в Debug выводится сообщение [This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.]

Comment: тогда вам надо указать, что relaod должен происходить на main thread. а кроме этого сообщения остальное работает?

Comment: задуманное работает, т.е. получается не красиво конечно, а именно приложение запускается с пустыми строками, а через секунд 15-20 уже строки заполняются нужными данными. как нибудь можно сделать сначала загрузку данных и во время этого был прогресс бар, который показывал скачивание данных, а потом уже с этими данными создавалась таблица?

Comment: можно, почему нет - сделайте флаг, и пока данные грузятся показывайте одну ячейку с прогресс баром в ней, либо вообще не показывайте таблицу, а показывайте прогресс бар.